# Unexpected output found while dealing with a pointer to an array

Tags: c, pointers, printf, implicit-conversion, pointer-arithmetic

when i tried to understand more about how array name is treated as pointer, I wrote this code :

```
#include<stdio.h> 
   
int main() 
{ 
  int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}; 
  printf("%d \n",*(&a+1));
  printf("%d \n",**(&a+1));
  return 0; 
}
```

and the output is

```
6422304
6422284
```

I expect the first output will be address and the second will be value stored in address, Not two output is addresses

Comment: What are you intending with `**(&a + 1)`? Using more sensible notation like `*a[1]`.

Comment: Start with simpler things. What will be printed for passing `a` to `printf` vs `&a` ? Can you explain this?

Answer (score 3):

You declared an array of 6 integers

```
int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
```

That is the array has the type `int[6]`.

The expression `&a` has the pointer type `int ( * )[6]`. And the expression `&a+1` points to the memory after the array. So dereferencing the array like `*(&a+1)` you will get an expression of the array type `int[6]` that in turn is implicitly converted to a pointer of the type `int *`,

And in this call of printf

```
printf("%d \n",*(&a+1));
```

you are trying to output the pointer using the conversion specifier `%d` that invokes undefined behavior.

Instead you could write

```
printf("%p \n",( void * )*(&a+1));
```

and the value of the pointer expression (that points to the memory after the array) will be outputted.

In this call of `printf`

```
printf("%d \n",**(&a+1));
```

you are dereferencing the expression `*(&a+1)` explained above. As the value of the obtained pointer expression points beyond the array then dereferencing it invokes undefined behavior.

Instead of these two calls you could write for example using the expression `&a`

```
printf("%p \n",( void * )*(&a));
```

to output the address of the first element of the array and'

```
printf("%d \n",**(&a));
```

to output the value of the first element of the array.

Though it would be simpler to write

```
printf("%p \n",( void * )a );
```

and

```
printf("%d \n",*a );
```

And you will get the same result.

Or to output for example the address and the value of the second element of the array you could write

```
printf("%p \n",( void * )( a  + 1 ));
```

and

```
printf("%d \n",*(a + 1 ) );
```

The last call of `printf` is equivalent to

```
printf("%d \n",a[1] ) );
```

Pay attention to that array designators used in expressions with rare exceptions are converted to pointers to their first elements.

Answer (score 0):

`a` is an array, which is also a pointer to a block of memory. So you can use `*a` to access the first value of the array, and `*(a + 1)` to access the next.

`*(a + 1)` works because the compiler knows the type of `a` is "pointer to integer". So adding 1 to it will give the address of the integer immediately after it.

Comment: "a is an array, which is also a pointer to a block of memory." - arrays and pointers are two different entities.:)

Comment: arrays and pointers are treated differently by the compiler, yes. But we can think of arrays as pointers to a block of memory, right?

Comment: Strictly speaking it is not correct. Arrays in expressions with rare exceptions are indeed converted to pointers to their first elements.